# How to sort numpy.recarray based on datetime field

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sorting, datetime, recarray

I have built a recarray with `np.rec.fromarrays` and following structure :

```
dtype=np.dtype([('layers', 'U256'), ('hours', datetime.datetime), ('points', 'U256')]))
```

I get an object like this :

```
[('image1.jpg', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 20), 'mypoints.points')
 ('image2.jpg', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 15), 'mypoints.points')]
```

with `recarray` type. I want to sort my recarray based on the second column containing `datetime`. I tried `numpy.recarray.sort` but it returns a NoneType object. I use it like this :

```
mytable.sort(order='hours')
```

I also tried to pass `kind='quicksort'` to the function but doesn't understand its usefulness.

Comment: Array `sort` acts in-place.  Hence the `None` return.  See its docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your data

```
x1=np.array(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'])
x2=np.array([datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 10), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 9)])
x3=np.array(['mypoints.points', 'mypoints.points'])
    
array = np.rec.fromarrays([x1, x2, x3], dtype=np.dtype([('layers', 'U256'), ('hours', datetime.datetime), ('points', 'U256')]))
```

Output:

```
rec.array([('image1.jpg', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 20), 'mypoints.points'),
           ('image2.jpg', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 15), 'mypoints.points')],
          dtype=[('layers', '<U256'), ('hours', 'O'), ('points', '<U256')])
```

But was not able to get same error... `array.sort(order='hours')` works fine

```
rec.array([('image2.jpg', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 15), 'mypoints.points'),
           ('image1.jpg', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 20), 'mypoints.points')],
          dtype=[('layers', '<U256'), ('hours', 'O'), ('points', '<U256')])
```

Comment: I copied the exact same code than yours and I get a None object for `array.sort(order='hours')`... what version of numpy are you using ?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see the output type of `recarray.sort`which is None. The function modifies the object itself...